# Add a custom button to plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, form-fields-types, styling

I need to add a custom button to the toolbar inside of a system plugin, near 'save', 'save & close' and 'close' buttons.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom button by working on event `onAfterRender()` and add your html/js code in the content.

Below is a sample code snippet you can add your code in this one.

```
function onAfterRender()
    {
        $option = Jfactory::getApplication()->input->get('option', '');
        if($option != 'com_config'){
            return true;
        }

        // Only render for HTML output
        if (JFactory::getDocument()->getType() !== 'html' ) { return; }

        //ADD HTML and JavaScript for your custom button
        $html = '';

        $body = JFactory::getApplication()->getBody(false);
        $body = str_replace('</body>', $html.'</body>', $body);
        JFactory::getApplication()->setBody($body);
        return true;
    }
```